# Is there a work around/ fix to crashing Xamarin Forms Apps ? Apps that crash on start up to be exact

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

New to Xamarin Forms. Any fix/work-around to a crashing on start-up issue ? Archived was a simple app with a Label element saying "Hello". The app  was archived in .apk format and installed on a Samsung tablet running Android 4.4. The app instantly crashes when started up. Any solution to this ?

Comment: Yes.  Determine the cause of the crash and fix it.  Look at the Android logs, or install a crash logging tool like AppCenter.ms, or install directly from VS and see what the debugger tells you about the crash.

Comment: Please, edit your question and include some logs of what happens when you start the application.

Comment: Hi! Try to connect the samsung tablet to your computer and debug the application to check where it crash. Also you could try an emulator with the same Android version

Comment: It could be anything and if you don't find anything suspicions in log regarding your source code, one thing I would recommend to try:  Decrease Android Min required Version in your Android Project Properties -> Android Manifest. This helps in some cases. Best regards.